# Теряется объявление функции jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, wordpress, плагин, функции

Пишу свой первый сложный, для меня скрипт, чат. Так вот, в форме для отправки сообщений используется `CKEDITOR`. Форма появляется только если юзер авторизован. Проблема в том, что после `Ajax` авторизации консоль выдает ошибку, что функции `ckeditor` не существует. Тоже самое при выходе, форма подгружается, но консоль пишет что функции `draggable` не существует. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решил, нужно было перенести все скрипты вниз сайта.

Answer (score 0):

а ещё можно при подключении скриптов указывать зависимости, тем самым указывая порядок подключения скриптов

Comment: Я знаю про зависимости, и мои скрипты тоже были внизу, было еще два плагина, скрипты которых подключались в хедере, из-за этого jquery тоже был в хедере. Вообщем, все скрипты внизу, и всё работает.